Haproxy timeout for downloading file
I cannot find a timeout specified for downloading file. It seems to be unlimited so far. When i make normal request with:
<?php

for($i = 0; $i < 120;$i){
echo 1; sleep(1);
}

Im getting easily 504 timeout. But not when downloading file...
Its possible to control it?
HAProxy version 2.4.24-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 2023/10/31 - https://haproxy.org/
Status: long-term supported branch - will stop receiving fixes around Q2 2026.
Known bugs: http://www.haproxy.org/bugs/bugs-2.4.24.html
Running on: Linux 5.15.0-119-generic #129-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 2 19:25:20 UTC 2024 x86_64

My config looks like that:
global
    stats timeout 30s

    # Performance Tuning
    maxconn 16384
    ulimit-n 65535
    spread-checks 3
    quiet

    # Default SSL material locations
    ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
    crt-base /etc/ssl/private

    # intermediate configuration
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE->
    ssl-default-bind-ciphersuites TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
    ssl-default-bind-options prefer-client-ciphers no-sslv3 no-tlsv10 no-tlsv11 no-tls-tickets

    ssl-default-server-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DH>
    ssl-default-server-ciphersuites TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
    ssl-default-server-options no-sslv3 no-tlsv10 no-tlsv11 no-tls-tickets

    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
defaults
    log     global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    timeout connect 5s
    timeout client  60s
    timeout server  60s
    timeout check   7s
    timeout http-request   50s
    timeout http-keep-alive   50s
    timeout queue  5s
    timeout tunnel  60s
    timeout client-fin  5s
    timeout server-fin  5s
frontend f-https
    log /dev/log    local0
    log /dev/log    local1 notice
    mode http
    option httplog
    option forwardfor
    option http-server-close
    option httpclose
    default_backend b-xxx-http
backend b-xxx-http
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option forwardfor
    http-check send meth GET uri / ver HTTP/1.1 hdr Host xxx.com
    http-check expect status 200
    cookie xxx insert indirect nocache secure
    server xxx k8s-istio:443 ssl verify none check-sni xxx.com sni str(xxx.com) cookie xxx

And the curl on verbose looks like that:
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying IP:443...
* Connected to xxx.com (IP) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [122 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Finished (20):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
{ [19 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [5370 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
{ [520 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
{ [52 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Finished (20):
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
} [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [52 bytes data]
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: xxxx
*  start date: x 00:00:00 2024 GMT
*  expire date: x 23:59:59 2025 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "xxx.com" matched cert's "xxx"
*  issuer: C=NL; O=GEANT Vereniging; CN=GEANT OV RSA CA 4
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multiplexing
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
} [5 bytes data]
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x55f154ae5eb0)
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
} [5 bytes data]
> GET /uploads/xxx.iso HTTP/2
> Host: xxx.com
> user-agent: curl/7.81.0
> accept: */*
>
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
{ [57 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
{ [57 bytes data]
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
< HTTP/2 200
< date: Thu, 05 Dec 2024 11:47:18 GMT
< content-type: application/octet-stream
< content-length: 22316234752
< last-modified: Wed, 04 Dec 2024 13:12:27 GMT
< etag: "6750553b-53226b800"
< x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< accept-ranges: bytes
< set-cookie: HAID="8448953edbd00aa5"; Max-Age=43200; HttpOnly
< set-cookie: xxx=xxx; path=/; Secure
< cache-control: private
<
{ [14829 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
  2 20.7G    2  596M    0     0  67.4M      0  0:05:15  0:00:08  0:05:07 70.0M* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
etc.

The browser just sending request and in 20ms its done.
Then after downloading I can see 2 entries in haproxy logs
Dec  5 13:05:17 haproxy-internal haproxy[1939108]: 10.100.0.xx:29351 [05/Dec/2024:13:01:25.363] f-https~ xxx/xxx 0/0/4/10/232188 200 22316235123 - - --NI 8/8/0/0/0 0/0 "GET /xxx/xxx.iso HTTP/1.1"
Dec  5 13:05:17 haproxy-internal haproxy[1939108]: 10.100.0.xx:29351 [05/Dec/2024:13:01:25.363] f-https~ xxx/xxx 0/0/4/10/232188 200 22316235123 - - --NI 8/8/0/0/0 0/0 "GET /xxx/xxx.iso HTTP/1.1"

